# Excel Offset Formula using a Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I want to use OFFSET to get an average of a range of 7 cells, then hop one cell to the right and get the average of the next range of 7 cells, and continue.

I know how to do this with one cells:

[image]

But I'm struggling to change this formula to work with ranges. Image below shows the ranges i would like to show data for:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the Non Volatile INDEX to the Volatile OFFSET.

Volatile means it will recalculate *EVERY TIME* excel calculates regardless of whether the underlying data changes or not.  So if this workbook is open, no matter if the calculation is initiated on a different worksheet or workbook, it will recalculate these cells.

The INDEX will only recalculate if the underlying data recalculates:

IN B4:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX('5+000"s'!$53:$53,(ROW(1:1)-1) * 7 + 2):INDEX('5+000"s'!$53:$53,(ROW(1:1)-1) * 7 + 8))
```

Then copy down.

The `7` are the spacing, there are 7 cells per average.

The `2` and `8` are the first columns used. `2` for `B` and `8` for `H`.

Then as the formula is dragged down the column numbers references will jump by seven each time.

Comment: Does exactly what I want! Thanks for the explanation Scott!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `B4`:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$53,0,ROW()-4,1,7))
```

You messed up with two last arguments of `OFFSET()` which should be height (1) and width (7) of the range you need.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I wanted the cell to hop one cell to the right of the last range used, see cell references in the 2nd image. It was difficult to explain so my apologies!